# Listen for command/ctrl + L signal in terminal

Tags: node.js, terminal, signals, stdout

Traditionally, command/ctrl + (lowercase L)  in a terminal will clear it.

I can clear the terminal using Node.js by writing this to stdout:

```
  process.stdout.write('\x1Bc');
```

but how can I listen for signals specifically a "command + l" key combination? (that is a lowercase L).

I think with Node.js the answer is probably related to:
`readline.emitKeypressEvents`
https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_emitkeypressevents_stream_interface

Comment: I assume that `ctrl + l` represents a signal to the terminal, but I can't find that info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)

Comment: Actually Ctrl+L is not a signal, more like a 'known keybind' to libraries such as readline. If you're not able to use the `readline` module or not writing an interactive shell, I'd look into what termcaps are.

Comment: ok interesting that's what I was thinking, so how can I capture it?

Comment: I'm not really sure, hence why I'm not writing an answer, but I think it definetely involves using the 'raw mode' of a stream and surely checking the pressed character against 0x0c.

Comment: yeah generally unless you hit return or write a newline, the 'data' event of the process.stdin stream won't fire...not sure how to capture it there yet

Comment: yeah, I wonder how I capture ctrl-D also, that is not a signal either, but looking to be able to capture that too if possible

Answer (score 1):

I dig up a bit and wrote a quick script as a proof of concept. That is an example of handling Ctrl-C, Ctrl-D and Ctrl-L signals AND having an event listener on new lines, even with raw mode enabled.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.stdin.currentLine = '';
process.stdin.setRawMode(true);

process.stdin.on('data', (buf) => {
    const charAsAscii = buf.toString().charCodeAt(0);

    switch (charAsAscii) {
        case 0x03:
            console.log('You pressed Ctrl-C. Sending SIGINT.')
            process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGINT');
            break;

        case 0x04:
            console.log('You pressed Ctrl-D. Bye!')
            process.exit(0);
            break;

        case 0x0c:
            console.log('You pressed Ctrl-L. Clearing screen.')
            break;

        case 0x0d:
            process.stdin.emit('line', process.stdin.currentLine);
            process.stdin.currentLine = '';
            break;

        default:
            process.stdin.currentLine += String.fromCharCode(charAsAscii);
            break;
    }
});

process.stdin.on('line', line => console.log(`New line: ${line}`));
```

---

How does it work:

> When in raw mode, input is always available character-by-character, not including modifiers. Additionally, all special processing of characters by the terminal is disabled, including echoing input characters. Note that CTRL+C will no longer cause a SIGINT when in this mode.

With that in mind, you can convert the buffer you get in the 'data' event, and check if it's a SIGINT (Ctrl-C), a 'clear' command (Ctrl-L), an EOF (Ctrl-D), ...

If it's a normal character, it simply adds the character to an internal buffer. When the return key is pressed, a `line` event is emitted with the internal buffer as argument. Then, the internal buffer is reset to an empty string.

Comment: Any idea how to listen for `tab` key? That's an important one

Comment: `tab` should be `0x09`. I also forgot to add it to my example but you must handle `del`, which is `0x7f`.